# Spring boot error page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello I am trying to get familiar with Spring Boot (and other technologies like liquibase, spring security and so on), therefore I tried to setup a simple application:

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.welcome</groupId>
    <artifactId>welcome</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>welcome</name>
    <description>Spring boot application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/resources/filters/local/db.properties</filter>
                </filters>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/resources/filters/dev/db.properties</filter>
                </filters>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Here is my project structure:

```
|__ src
   |__ main
      |__ java
         |__ com.test.welcome
            |__ WelcomeApplication.java
               |__ controller
                  |__ WelcomeController.java   
      |__ resources
         |__ static
            |__ css
               |__ custom.css
            |__ js
               |__ custom.js
         |__ application.properties
         |__ liquibase.properties
      |__ webapp
         |__ WEB-INF
            |__ jsp
               |__ welcome.jsp
```

My WelcomeApplication.java looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WelcomeApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WelcomeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The WelcomeController.java looks like this:

```
@Controller
    public class WelcomeController {

        @RequestMapping("/welcome")
        public String loginMessage(){
            return "welcome";
        }
    }
```

application.properties contains the following content:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#Debug Level
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO

#DB configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#Liquibase configuration
liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

management.security.enabled=false
```

And the welcome.jsp file looks like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <caption>Your todos are</caption>
            <thead>


 <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Target Date</th>
            <th>Is it Done?</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Todo 1</td>
            <td>10/12/2017</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/edit-todo">Edit Todo</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/delete-todo">Delete Todo</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="/add-todo">Add a Todo</a>

    </div>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start the application (http://localhost:8080/welcome) I always get:

[image]

I know that this page appears if Spring does not find any other html page to show. However I followed many guides and check all the folder-structure and I dont know why it cant find my welcome.jsp file.

I also know that spring auto scan starts from classes in package where @SpringBootConfiguration(WelcomeApplication.java) is defined and
 * that include classes in sub-packages of @SpringBootConfiguration class.
Therefore he should find my controller in the subpackage "controller".

I managed to get all the other stuff working (Liquibase configuration and so on), however I cannot do this 1 simple thing. I think I am missing something...

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: @JBNizet thx but I already saw that example in GitHub but I still dont know what I am doing wrong. My project structure and configuration seems to be correct

Comment: My link doesn't even point to an example in github. Click on it.

Comment: Yeah I know it is the Spring Boot Reference Guide. I also enter the correct password (printen in the console) when I load my page (because of Spring-Security). Can you pls just give me a hint to which point you are exactly refering to?  That would be really helpful

Comment: Jesus, click on it, and read. It points to a chapter of the guide named "JSP limitations". Read that chapter. It's 8 lines long.

Comment: If you are refering to the limitations that if it is possible to use: <packaging>JAR</packaging> and to put the jsp's in the jsp-Folder, then yes it is possible with Spring Boot. So I am trying to get this work. Thats why I added the tomcat-embed-jasper dependency.

Comment: Ah, sure, if you think the official spring boot documentation lies... My bet would be that it doesn't.

Comment: @JBNizet Even if I change the packaging to war, I still se the error page. IWhen I try to link jsp to the common controller, I end up with Whitelabel error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JB Nizet stated in his comments, it is about the limitations defined in the -
[Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/)